# R - Carry last observation varied number of times

Tags: r, repeat, locf

I have a lengthy dataset with one column containing cruise ships present/absent in one of two (or one in each at the same time) locations (A or B) in a bay. Currently, I have the cruise ship data matched to a series of timestamps for every half hour for several months in a row. I want to carry forward the A's and or B's a varied number of times to represent presence/absence on this new timescale. Each cruise ship is present a varied number of times (in hours).

I start with something like this:

```
     [,1]    [,2] [,3]
[1,] "Ship1" "A"  "4" 
[2,] "Ship2" "B"  "5" 
[3,] NA      NA   NA  
[4,] NA      NA   NA  
[5,] NA      NA   NA  
[6,] "Ship3" "A"  "2" 
[7,] NA      NA   NA
```

And I want this:

```
     [,1]    [,2]  [,3]
[1,] "Ship1" "A"   "4" 
[2,] "Ship2" "A,B" "5" 
[3,] NA      "A,B" NA  
[4,] NA      "A,B" NA  
[5,] NA      "B"   NA  
[6,] "Ship3" "A,B" "2" 
[7,] NA      "A"   NA
```

I've tried a few things to no avail (and some crashing):

```
data$fillAnchorA = na.locf(data$AnchorageA, na.rm = F, mingap = lag(data$hoursPresent))

data$fillAnchorB = rep(na.locf(data$AnchorageB, na.rm = F), length(data$hoursPresent))

data$fillAnchorB = rep(data$AnchorageB, length(mastercruisedata$hoursPresent))
```

(AnchorageA has all the cruise ships arriving to anchorage A (represented with A) and AnchorageB has the same for the ships going to anchorage B). "fillAnchorA" and "fillAnchorB" is where I want the desired output for (col2). I figured it would be easier to keep the A's and B's separate but maybe not? I'm at a bit of a loss here.

Comment: To clarify, cruise ships are present a varied number of HOURS. (Present a varied LENGTH of time). I need to know when there are times without any cruise ship in either area. Also, the timestamps are for every half hour, so the hoursPresent variable would need to be doubled to fill in the correct number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

DISCLAIMER: This is *brutal*. There must be a better way...

- First, I create the data frame.
- Next, I add a column with row indices for ease of referencing.
- I then create a fill function that takes the current row index, the number of repeats, the character to be repeated, and the number of rows in the data frame. That function produces arrays that contain either `NA` or runs of the character, `c`.
- Finally, I use `pmap` to run through the rows in the data frame that do not contain `NA`s, and create arrays, like described above, for each of these rows. A second `pmap` call goes through these arrays, pasting together sorted, unique, non-NA values. This is then added to the appropriate column of the original data frame.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
library(purrr)

# Create data frame
df <- data.frame(Ship = c("Ship1", "Ship2", NA, NA, NA, "Ship3", NA),  
                 l = c("A", "B", NA, NA, NA, "A", NA),  
                 r = c(4, 5, NA, NA, NA, 2, NA))

# Add row numbers
df %<>% 
  tibble::rowid_to_column() 

# Fill function
fill_foo <- function(id, n, c, nr = nrow(df)){
  tmp <- rep(NA, nr)
  tmp[id:(id+n-1)] <- as.character(c)
  tmp
}

# Go through each no-NA row
df$l <- with(df %>% na.omit(), pmap(list(rowid, r, l), fill_foo)) %>% 
  pmap(function(...)paste(sort(unique(na.omit(unlist(c(...))))), collapse = ",")) %>% 
  unlist

# Print results
print(df)
#>   rowid  Ship   l  r
#> 1     1 Ship1   A  4
#> 2     2 Ship2 A,B  5
#> 3     3  <NA> A,B NA
#> 4     4  <NA> A,B NA
#> 5     5  <NA>   B NA
#> 6     6 Ship3 A,B  2
#> 7     7  <NA>   A NA
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>